# hiding the listviews after it is clicked

Tags: android, scroll, visibility

I have a listview and when it is clicked then it has to be invisible. It works perfectly fine but when the screen is scrolled up and down those which are invisible again reappears. Does anybody know how to fix these.

Here is my code snippets for the ListItemClick

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
             v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                 Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

                 Contact1 c = (Contact1) o;     

                 Toast.makeText(this, c.getDisplayName(),
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                 Toast.makeText(this, c.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 ids.add(c.getDisplayName()); 




            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because every time the list is scrolled , the listview's adapter's `getView()` method gets called where the listitems are generated again. SO for your need you need to have a custom adapter and override its `getView` method, and in it

```
@override

public View getView(View view) //Just a mock method, do not copy paste
{

   if(!isVisible[position]){ // isVisible is an array which holds whether a view at position is visible or not
      //make it invicsible here
    }
  return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much your suggestion worked exactly the way I wanted :-)

Answer (score 1):

The item, I'm going to assume it is a `Contact1` object, is still in the array (or whatever container you are using to hold the items).

You will need to one of two things:

1) remove the item from the array then regenerate the list view

2) keep a list of the invisible items (like sandy suggested) and then not create a view for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you using custom adapter and want to hide on scroll also then you need to maintain one flag as list view is clicked then inside `getView()`make your listview or listview items based on positions or you can hide all as invisible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for that BaseAdpter and according to view position make it visible and invisible

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ContactInfo> mlist;
    Context mcontext;
   // this arraylist used to contains click item

   List<String> checkednamelist;

public ContactsAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<ChatInfo> mchtlist) {   

        checkednamelist = new ArrayList<String>();   
        mlist =  mchtlist;
        mcontext = context;    
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int postion) {
    return mlist.get(postion);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewgroup){
        View view = null;
        if(convertview == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrow, null);

            ContactHolder holder = new ContactHolder();

            holder.txtviewfirstname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            holder.txtviewphone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            holder.chkselected = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);




chkselected .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
   // here you can add selected item name for make it invisible from list
  checkednamelist.add("Stringvalures");


});

  // this code is helps to achieve that
try{
            if (checkednamelist.contains("yourstringname")) {
                            // here make visible your cotrol
                chkleft.setChecked(true);
                chkleft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

                            // here make Invisible your cotrol
                chkleft.setChecked(false);
                chkleft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }   
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception while checkbox make unchecked when scrolling"+e);
        }

        view.setTag(holder);

    }
        else{
            view = convertview;
        }
        ContactHolder holder2 = (ContactHolder) view.getTag();
        holder2.txtviewfirstname.setText(list.get(position).firstname);
        holder2.txtviewphone.setText(list.get(position).phonenumber);
        holder2.chkselected.setChecked(list.get(position).selected);
        return view;
    }
```

}